# double double parentheses javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax

I found this code in a book:

```
function foo() {
  console.log( this.a );
}

var a = 2;
var o = { a: 3, foo: foo };
var p = { a: 4 };
o.foo(); // 3
(p.foo = o.foo)(); // 2
```

What does last line mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last line is doing an assignment and then calling the function.

Assignment happens first

```
(p.foo = o.foo)
```

Then call the function

```
(p.foo = o.foo)();
```

In this second call to foo, it is being called outside of the scope of p or o, so it's essentially the same as calling:

```
foo();
```

Comment: is this equal to p.foo = o.foo; p.foo();

Comment: but if you run the code
(p.foo = o.foo)(); prints 2
p.foo = o.foo; p.foo(); prints 4

Comment: @user1272913: They're not equivalent. The value of `this` in the function invocation will be the `window` object because the function, as the result of the parens, is detached from any object. It's more equivalent to `var f = (p.foo = o.foo); f();`

Comment: If you call p.foo(), you are calling it on the p object in which the variable a is scoped to p. In the example `(p.foo = o.foo)();` you are assigning a function and then calling it outside of the scope of either variable, therefore making it use the variable a defined with a value of 2.

Comment: "you are assigning a function and then calling it outside of the scope of either variable," I am assigning it to p.foo right? and then call p.foo???

Comment: Updated my answer a bit, I didn't initially notice the values you were asking about.

Comment: @user1272913: when you do `p.foo()`, the value of `this` inside the `foo` method is the `p` object. This happens automatically. If you detach the `foo` function from the `p` object before invoking it, the value of `this` gets set to the `window` object by default. Your `a` variable is a global variable, so it appears as a property of `window`, and so you get `2`.

Comment: You're assigning a reference to a function and then calling that function.

Comment: ok I think I got it: this is equivalent to: c=p.foo=o.foo;c()