# Double parentheses But not IIFE or closures,What is it? is it Valid JS syntax?

Tags: javascript, node.js

i was trying to learn and understand KnexJS source Code, until i came to a block of code which i don't have any idea what is it.

```
  config = (0, _lodash.assign)({}, config, {
  connection: (0, _parseConnection2.default)(config.connection).connection
});
```

in Simplified version

```
config = (0, Args1)({}, config, {Args2});
```

what makes me  confused is that,there is no 'function' keywords or any 'identifier' before the parentheses...

i have found same but not  similiar question here: [double parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486148/double-double-parentheses-javascript) and that is understandable and different...is it Valid JS? if Yes, what it's mean?

Comment: It's just a function call.

Comment: Can you please give some resources to understand this syntax ?

Comment: @Teemu first of all thanks && please correct me if i'm worng.. from what i understand an IIFE  should have function(either with 'function' keyword or 'name' identifier) in the first Parentheses.

Comment: @RafikTighilt lib/index.js directory on [link](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex)  after clone you have to 'npm install' to show the lib dir

Comment: @Teemu ok, than call to which function?

Comment: For the details, see CertainPerformances's answer below, or the linked dup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the comma operator (evaluates a comma-separated list of expressions, resolving to the value of the last expression), combined with a call of `_lodash.assign` with a global calling context, rather than a calling context of `_lodash`. Here's a simpler example:

```js
const obj = {
  abc: function(arg) {
    console.log(this);
    console.log('abc called with ' + arg);
  }
}
obj.abc('foo');
(0, obj.abc)('foo')
```

As you can see, calling `obj.abc` alone results in the calling context being `obj`, while `(0, obj.abc)('foo')` results in the calling context being `window`. I think it's a minification technique - saner, more understandable code would look like

```
obj.abc.call(window, 'foo')
```

or

```
const theFn = obj.abc;
theFn('foo')
```

Comment: Thank , I'm still beginner but you explanation is simply understandable..

Comment: The "Keyword" there is the "Comma Operator"